# case statement with pairs giving incorrect value

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

query with results as below:

```
 b_id| l_id | result    | Count | avg
-----+------+--------- -+-------+-----
   1 |   10 | Limited   |   2   | 66.66
   1 |   10 |Significant|   1   | 33.33
   2 |   09 | Critical  |   1   |100.00
```

I am struggling to get a query right using a case statement as below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (b_id, l_id) b_id, l_id, 
            (CASE
                WHEN result = 'Critical' THEN 'Critical'
                WHEN result = 'Significant' AND avg >= 50 THEN 'Critical'
                WHEN result = 'Significant' AND result <> 'Critical' THEN 'Significant'
                WHEN result = 'Medium' AND avg >= 50 THEN 'Medium'
                ELSE 'Limited' END) as cr                   
From (sub query)
```

the results that I am getting are as below:

```
 b_id| l_id | result    
-----+------+----------
   1 |   10 | Limited   
   2 |   09 | Critical
```

but what I am expecting is as below:

```
 b_id| l_id | result    
-----+------+----------
   1 |   10 | significant   
   2 |   09 | Critical
```

1). if there is atleast 1 critical then critical. 
2) when there is significant => 50 % and no critical then critical(that means if there is only 1 row and that is significant so it is 100% then 'critical')
3) if there is atleast 1 significant, no critical and (medium, limited) > significant then significant
 4) if medium is >= 50% and no (critical or significant) then medium
 5) rest will be limited.

I need Significant rather than limited because the highest value trumps a lower value in most cases so Sig trumps Ltd. Overall I want the case statement to assess the group of pairs (b_id,l_id) so in the group of pairs for 1 | 10 I need the case statement to assess and return a result.

Comment: This is a bit paradoxical: `WHEN result = 'Significant' AND result <> 'Critical'`

Comment: Your logic for expecting `Significant` instead of `Limited` is not clear to me.

Comment: Sorry I'll make my case statement clear.

Comment: `DISTINCT ON` without `ORDER BY` just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry I'll make my case statement clear. 1). if there is atleast 1 critical then critical. 2) when there is significant => 50 % and no critical then critical(that means if there is only 1 row and that is significant so it is 100% then 'critical'), 3) if there is atleast 1 significant, no critical and (medium, limited) > significant then significant. 4) if medium is >= 50% and no (critical or significant) then medium, 5) rest will be limited.

Comment: @taz, although your CASE statement is a bit confusing, it is not actually the source of the unexpected output here. Your use of DISTINCT ON is the problem; see my answer for the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bool_or aggregate (At least the condition is true for one row ) :

```
SELECT b_id, l_id,CASE WHEN bool_or(result='Critical' or (result = 'Significant' AND avg >= 50) ) Then 'Critical' 
           WHEN bool_or(result='Significant') THEN 'Significant'
           WHEN bool_or(result = 'Medium' AND avg >= 50) THEN 'Medium'
           ELSE 'Limited' END as cr 
 From (sub query) group by 1,2
```

Comment: Thanks Remy, I found a solution which is working, but I have to use multiple sub query's for it to work. I tested your solution which is better then mine. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `WHEN result = 'Significant' AND result <> 'Critical' THEN 'Significant'` issue aside*, all three rows qualify and then one one of the first two rows gets selected because of `DISTINCT ON (b_id, l_id)`. You can't control which of the two rows will be selected, that is basically a function of how your data is organized on disk and that may change over time.

You will never get a row with `1 |   10 | Critical` because the corresponding row from the table has `result = 'Significant'` but the `avg = 33.33` so it can not become `'Critical'`. If you want to favour rows with "Critical" over "Significant" over "Medium" over "Limited", then you should add a specific clause for that, such as a table with a numerical value assigned to each `result` level such that you can sort on it.

** `CASE` statements are evaluated only up to the point where a final result is obtained, so when the first sub-clause matches, remaining clauses are not evaluated.*

Comment: Hi Patrick, you are right. I edited the question from critical to significant. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Patrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37055319/20789) is correct but I'll expand on it a bit to make the contradiction/problem in your query more explicit.

The table or subquery that you're starting with contains these **3** rows, which are each distinct if you consider **all** of their columns:

```
 b_id| l_id | result    | Count | avg
-----+------+--------- -+-------+-----
   1 |   10 | Limited   |   2   | 66.66
   1 |   10 |Significant|   1   | 33.33
   2 |   09 | Critical  |   1   |100.00
```

However, the query that you're running uses `DISTINCT ON` with only **2** columns:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (b_id, l_id) b_id, l_id, …
```

What you're explicitly telling PostgreSQL here is, "I only want to see distinct output rows, but I want you to consider two output rows to be distinct based *only* on the values in the `b_id` and `l_id` columns."

Therein lies the contradiction:

- All 3 rows are distinct if you consider **all** their columns
- … but there are only two distinct tuples for `(b_id, l_id)`: `(1,10)` and `(2,09)`.

Because you specifically told PostgreSQL to consider the first two rows as **not distinct**, it picks only *one* of these rows to use in the output, and it picks this row arbitrarily as Patrick explains.

I am not sure why you are using `DISTINCT ON (x, y, z)` in the first place. If you simply replace it with `DISTINCT` (on all columns) then the query will return the results you expect:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b_id, l_id, 
            (CASE
                WHEN result = 'Critical' THEN 'Critical'
                WHEN result = 'Significant' AND avg >= 50 THEN 'Critical'
                WHEN result = 'Significant' THEN 'Significant'
                WHEN result = 'Medium' AND avg >= 50 THEN 'Medium'
                ELSE 'Limited' END) as cr                   
From (sub query)
```

(I've also removed the redundant `result <> 'Critical'` which others noted.)

Comment: Hi Dan, when I use "DISTINCT (on all columns)" then I am get all the three rows as they are unique. The reason I mentioned distinct on (u_id, l_id) because, I want only 2 rows (1,10, significant) and (1, 9, critical). Thanks

Comment: Thanks Dan, you help explain, but the code you provided assesses every row with the case statement and gives a result at row level. What I am trying to achieve it to assess the data at set level and get 1 result per SET. My 'sets' being groups of pairs (u_id,l_id). How can I do this?

Comment: Given that multiple rows from within the sets may result in **different results**, how do you propose to select the correct result for the sett? In this example, why should the (1,10) rows result in `significant` rather than `limited`, given that there is one row for each result?

Comment: I *suspect* that what you are looking for here is something involving `group by` and aggregate functions. This is the "normal" way to combine multiple rows into a single row in a predictable way in SQL. If you are new to SQL and don't know exactly what you're doing, you shouldn't be using `DISTINCT ON` at all?

Answer (score 0):

```
select b_id, l_id, (CASE WHEN result = 'Critical' THEN 'Critical'
            WHEN (result = 'Significant' AND avg >= 50) THEN 'Critical'
            WHEN result = 'Significant' THEN 'Significant'
            WHEN result = 'Medium' AND avg >= 50 THEN 'Medium'
            WHEN result = 'Limited' THEN 'Limited' END) as result
from (
    select business_unit_id, law_id, result, avg
from (
    SELECT b_id, l_id, avg, result, ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY b_id, l_id order by CASE
            WHEN result = 'Critical' THEN 1
            WHEN result = 'Significant' AND avg >= 50 THEN 1
            WHEN result = 'Significant' THEN 2
            WHEN result = 'Medium' AND avg >= 50 THEN 3
            WHEN result = 'Limited' THEN 4 END) as rownum

from (
    sub_query     ) b            ) x where rownum = 1              ) y
```